# Split delimited string into new rows with type conversion set to TRUE

Tags: r, string, split, data.table

*data.table::tstrsplit* has a useful *type.convert* argument. But it errors out when after the split each row gets converted into a different class, see example:

```
library(data.table)

x <- fread("CHROM POS REF ALT TYPE AF
chr1 1 A T MISSENSE 0.23
chr2 1 A T,G MISSENSE 0.17,0.09")
```

In ALT column we have "T" and "T,G", so first row gets converted to logical "TRUE", and the second row gets split and converted into character "T" and "G". As a result we get below error:

```
x[, lapply(.SD, function(x) unlist(tstrsplit(x, ",", fixed = TRUE, type.convert = TRUE))),
  by = .(CHROM, POS, REF, TYPE)]

# Error in `[.data.table`(x, , lapply(.SD, function(x) unlist(tstrsplit(x,  : 
#   Column 1 of result for group 2 is type 'character' but expecting type
#   'logical'. Column types must be consistent for each group.
```

We could avoid auto conversion, and convert later manually, all great:

```
x[, lapply(.SD, function(x) unlist(tstrsplit(x, ",", fixed = TRUE))),
  by = .(CHROM, POS, REF, TYPE)][, .(CHROM, POS, REF, ALT, TYPE, AF = as.numeric(AF))]
#    CHROM POS REF ALT     TYPE   AF
# 1:  chr1   1   A   T MISSENSE 0.23
# 2:  chr2   1   A   T MISSENSE 0.17
# 3:  chr2   1   A   G MISSENSE 0.09
```

But *tidyr::separate* doesn't have this issue:

```
tidyr::separate_rows(x, ALT, AF, convert = TRUE)
# # A tibble: 3 x 6
#   CHROM   POS REF   ALT   TYPE        AF
#   <chr> <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>    <dbl>
# 1 chr1      1 A     T     MISSENSE  0.23
# 2 chr2      1 A     T     MISSENSE  0.17
# 3 chr2      1 A     G     MISSENSE  0.09
```

The question: is there a better **data.table** way to achieve this? I need to use type conversion as AF column needs to be numeric. I'd want to split delimited column simultaneously. In real data there might more than 2 columns with delimiters.

Comment: @akrun good one, but still would want to avoid this "extra" step. separate_rows looks so much tidier. If nothing else, this is the best so far, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done more easily with `cSplit`

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(x, c("ALT", "AF"), ",", "long")
#   CHROM POS REF ALT     TYPE   AF
#1:  chr1   1   A   T MISSENSE 0.23
#2:  chr2   1   A   T MISSENSE 0.17
#3:  chr2   1   A   G MISSENSE 0.09
```

---

Regarding the `data.table` option, another way is to add a space

```
x[, lapply(.SD, function(x) 
 trimws(unlist(tstrsplit(gsub("([TF])+", " \\1", x), ",", 
    fixed = TRUE, type.convert = TRUE)))),
    by = .(CHROM, POS, REF, TYPE)]
#   CHROM POS REF     TYPE ALT   AF
#1:  chr1   1   A MISSENSE   T 0.23
#2:  chr2   1   A MISSENSE   T 0.17
#3:  chr2   1   A MISSENSE   G 0.09
```

Comment: Another great option with trimws, but still I was hoping for more direct way of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

As the problem is that `type.convert` identifies `T` of the first group as a logical `TRUE`, you could use explicitely `type.convert` on the resulting `data.table` where you have also `G` in the variable, so you don't have this problem:

```
x[, lapply(.SD, function(x) unlist(str_split(x,","))),
           by = .(CHROM, POS, REF, TYPE)] %>% 
   type.convert(.,as.is = T)

   CHROM POS REF     TYPE ALT   AF
1:  chr1   1   A MISSENSE   T 0.23
2:  chr2   1   A MISSENSE   T 0.17
3:  chr2   1   A MISSENSE   G 0.09


$CHROM
[1] "character"

$POS
[1] "integer"

$REF
[1] "character"

$TYPE
[1] "character"

$ALT
[1] "character"

$AF
[1] "numeric"
```

Comment: sorry I did not see your comment (not here anymore ?)

Comment: it's okay.  I removed the comments.  But, then I thought not to include that in the answers as the OP was looking more of a direct one.  It is good that you came up with the same solution.  I was just saying.  You can keep those solution

Comment: You are way faster and better the me (and the other), it is nice that you volontary think of not including all the answers in your :)

Comment: It's good to have that option from your answer.  I think there is no direct way with `tstrsplit` unless we do some modification in the 'T', 'F' part

Comment: Yes, this was suggested by akrun already in the comments, I would want to avoid this step.